# Is there any month or time in the year that Haj&Umrah can not be done?

Tags: hajj, time, umrah

There are a specific time to do Haj in a year. But we can do Umrah in almost every day of a year. I want to know is there any dates that we cannot do Haj & Umrah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do Hajj at ANYTIME except its specified due time in the 12th month of Dhu al-Hijjah.

Umrah, on the other hand, is open ended; you can do it absolutely anytime. The best time for Umrah (the time when the Prophet (PBUH) did all of his 4 Umrahs) is the 11th Arabic month of Dhu al-Qa'dah.